# Group values in one column which share the same value in another column (pandas: groupby.apply/multi-index)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, apply

I am working with the following dataframe [This is only a portion of the df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itttv.png)

I want to create a multi-index dataframe where the top level index is the `title_no` and the sub-index is all of the `release_no` values that share the same `title_no`.

I have tried using the groupby.apply method but this groups the `release_no's` with the same `title_no` into lists and eliminates the rest of the columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('title_no')['release_no'].unique()).reset_index()
```

[This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/164CH.png)

Ideally, I would like my dataframe to look something like this:

```
title_no           release_no           name                     country_id

199034                                         

                   732644               Jurassic Park III        ES
                   891376               Jurassic Park III        CA
                   732658               Jurassic Park III        TH
199052

                   1119213              Myth of Fingerprints     IT
                   925041               Myth of Fingerprints     ES
                   448432               Myth of Fingerprints     US
                   564033               Myth of Fingerprints     FR

...
```

Is there a way to do this in pandas, where I could list out the rows under the same `title_no` and be able to index the rows on one level with `title_no`  and then with `release_no` on a lower level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a `groupby` for this; sorting will be sufficient:

```
df.sort_values(['title_no', 'release_no']).set_index(['title_no', 'release_no'])
```